# How to tell gmock to ignore any other method calls

Tags: googletest, googlemock

take a look at the code below

```
class ExampleInterface {
public:
   virtual void exMethod(int param)=0;
};

class MyMock : public ExampleInterface {
   MOCK_METHOD1(exMethod, void(int));
};

TEST_F(TestCls, test1){
  MyMock mock;

  EXPECT_CALL(mock, exMethod(4)).Times(1);

  mock.exMethod(4);
  mock.exMethod(5);
}
```

this test fails with message

```
...Expected: to be called once 
Actual: called once - saturated and active
```

I want this test to pass because I am not interested in other exMethod calls if they don't match the ecpect_call. how to tell gmock to ignore any calls that don't match the expectation?

Answer (score 2):

You could tell it to also expect to be called with any parameter any number of times:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, exMethod(_)).Times(AnyNumber());
EXPECT_CALL(mock, exMethod(4)).Times(1);
```

Note that the order of the expectations is important, as the most recent expectations take priority. If you put them the other way around the "_" matcher would match everything and the "4" matcher would never be satisfied.

Comment: I tried this approach but I thought that there is a simpler way then adding another expectation. For example, a parameter when starting all tests. in my opinon such behaviour of gmock is strange and should be changed

Comment: I think this is just the intentional design behavior for Google Mock.